# SQL Server Table Design with Table having foreign key to two other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Four tables,
DiscountCode which describes a discount.
Bundles which is basically sold as a product so it contains a productcode
Products which are sold as products so it also contains a productcode
ProductDiscount code meant to be used to describe the fact that a Bundle/Product can have multiple discount codes associated with it.

```
**Discount Code**
Id
Name
Code  ex. SUMMER10  ie 10% off summer products
...

**Bundles**
Id
Name
ProductCode  *Unique*  Ex..ABC123
...

**Products**
Id
Name
ProductCode  *Unique*  Ex.. XYZ1234
...

**ProductDiscountCode**
DiscountId
ProductCode   FK to both Products.ProductCode  AND Bundles.ProductCode

Records in ProductDiscountCode:
1   ABC123
1   XYZ1234
1   URS576  <-- prevent this if Prod or Bundle does NOT contain URS576
```

My question is in regards to the ProductCode in the Ternary table.  NOW KEEP IN MIND PELASE SQL IS NOT MY STRONG SUIT!  Can/Should the ProductCode column in the ternary table be foreign keyed to TWO Separate tables in an attempt to restrict it's content to a product code that is EITHER contained in the Bundle table  OR the Product table, assuming the productcode in bundles and products is unique between the two tables (to be enforced by business rules).  Or does the ProductDiscountCode table need the following

```
**ProductDiscountCode**
DiscountId
ProductCode  FK to ProductCode in Product
BundleCode   FK to ProductCode in Bundle
```

Comment: If you are doing table design, SQL needs to become your strong suit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use a Foreign Key then every value must exist as a key on the other table so you can't constrain your column Product Keys if it's got Bundle Keys in it and vice versa.

If you need to ensure referential integrity then you'll need to have two Nullable columns.

You should probably also have a Check Constraint to make sure that one and only one of the codes is null.

```
CREATE TABLE ProductDiscountCode
(
DiscountId int,
ProductCode  varchar(12) null,
BundleCode   varchar(12) null,

CONSTRAINT ProductDiscountCode_PK PRIMARY KEY(DiscountId),

CONSTRAINT FK_ProductDiscountCode_DiscountId FOREIGN KEY (DiscountId) REFERENCES DiscountCode (Id),
CONSTRAINT FK_ProductDiscountCode_BundleCode FOREIGN KEY (BundleCode) REFERENCES Bundle (ProductCode),
CONSTRAINT FK_ProductDiscountCode_ProductCode FOREIGN KEY (ProductCode) REFERENCES Product (ProductCode),

CONSTRAINT ProductCodeExists CHECK (
                                   (ProductCode IS NULL AND BundleCode IS NOT  NULL) 
                                   OR 
                                   (ProductCode IS NOT NULL AND BundleCode IS NULL)
                                   )
)
```

If for some reason you really need to be able to show the Product Codes as a single column then you could do something along these lines

```
CREATE TABLE ProductDiscountCode
(
DiscountId int,
SingleProductCode  varchar(12) null,
BundleCode   varchar(12) null,
ProductCode as ISNULL (SingleProductCode  ,BundleCode  ) ,
CONSTRAINT ProductDiscountCode_PK PRIMARY KEY(DiscountId),
CONSTRAINT FK_ProductDiscountCode_DiscountId FOREIGN KEY (DiscountId) REFERENCES DiscountCode (Id),
CONSTRAINT FK_ProductDiscountCode_BundleCode FOREIGN KEY (BundleCode) REFERENCES Bundle (ProductCode),
CONSTRAINT FK_ProductDiscountCode_SingleProductCode FOREIGN KEY (SingleProductCode) REFERENCES Product (ProductCode),
CONSTRAINT SingleProductCodeExists CHECK ((SingleProductCode IS NULL AND BundleCode IS NOT  NULL) OR (SingleProductCode IS NOT NULL AND BundleCode IS NULL))
)
```

But you do have to ask yourself first whether using Foreign key restraints is actually necessary in the first place.

Having two columns for product code could speed up your Select queries slightly but by having to decide which column you are storing the product code in the updates, deletes and inserts will be made more complicated.

Comment: But every value of ProductCode in the ProductDiscountCode table will have a ProductCode that exist in either Products or Bundles which doesn't that fill your first requirement?

Comment: For example ABC123 will either exist in Products OR Bundles, but never in both

Comment: Each Foreign Key constraint is a constraint in it's own right. If one is satisfied then that doesn't mean you break the other.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it is never a good idea to try to constrain to two differnt FKs for the same field, that is a sign of incorrect design.

Why is bundle a separate table if it is not using the product codes from the product table? WHy not add a column to the product table to identify if the line item is a bundle or an individual product and stopre both there?

Comment: Because bundles are sold as products and have their own product codes other than the ones of the products it contains...

Comment: Then since they are sold as products it is far better to put them inteh product table

Comment: The properties of a bundle are different then a individual product item...  think of it like an Xbox bundle including controllers... the controller sold as a single item has it's own properties and code unique to itself, but the box bundle including two controllers also has it's own properties and it's own unique product code, in our case we need to track which items are in the bundle though... that's why they are separated

Comment: No you put the bundle in the product table as it is a product and tehn you have a bundleProduct table (1-many realtionship) that has the bundle producctid as the bundle id and the individual elements prod of the products as the product id.  Then join to the product table twice to get the bundlename and the indivuidual  product names when querying.

Comment: I solved this exact problem at my last job, so I am familiar with what you are trying to accompplish.

Comment: Then what about the properties that differ between bundles and products... if they are all in the product table you have nulls in those columns...  defeats normalization doesn't it??

Comment: No, then you have a separate table with a one to one relationship (enforced by making teh Bundle productid the PK in the BundleDetails table) for properties that are for bundles only.

Answer (score 0):

Please first take a look at the thread: [Multiple foreign key constraints on a single column in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636356/multiple-foreign-key-constraints-on-a-single-column-in-sql-server-2008)

ProductCode is a FK in Bundle and then you want another foreign key to the same column in ProductDiscountCode. You are double referencing same field and that does not seem to be good designing. You should restrict the values in the table at the moment of the insert, constraints are not meant for all kinds of validations.